# Web scraping hidden table in R/Python

Tags: python, r, web, web-scraping, html-table

I would like to scrape the table in this website: http://www.eloratings.net/2000. I can see the table when I'm inspecting the elements, but it is hidden from source, hence I can't scrape it with the usual methods.

Can you help me with that? Any help either in R or Python would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table is built using XHR calls like:

http://www.eloratings.net/teams.tsv?_=1615377480093
http://www.eloratings.net/tournaments.tsv?_=1615377480094
http://www.eloratings.net/en.labels.tsv?_=1615377480096

Use the browser F12 (devtools) -> Network -> XHR and see the calls you need.